# How to know which sessions where killed in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2012 via Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio.

I executed the following command:

```
Kill 54
SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
req.session_id,
req.status,
req.command,
req.cpu_time,
req.total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
```

My intention was to show the active sessions after the kill, but I got an error.
After deleting only the kill command and reexecuting, I have got the following message:
Command succesfully completed.

I am on a production server, so I got worried if I killed some critical process.

My question is how to find the killed sessions and by which user.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: [Who Killed My SQL Server Process?](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/b/weblog/archive/2012/05/03/who-killed-my-sql-server-process)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My intention was to show the active sessions after the kill, but I got
>   an error. After deleting only the kill command and reexecuting, I have
>   got the following message: Command succesfully completed.

insert a GO after the KILL

```
kill 54
GO
Select ....
```

> I am on a production server, so I got worried if I killed some
>   critical process.
>
> My question is how to find the killed sessions and by which user.

run the query first to make sure you are terminating the right process.